# Meteor Account UI Bootstrap Login Callback

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to modify this package of Meteor [meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3](https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3)

How can I define my own callback function when user login success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(user) {
  //this is the callback
});
```

And for example you could use it to go to some route or to obtain the userId.

> Example

```
Accounts.onLogin(function () {
  Router.go("admin");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that I need to override their function.

Comment: Can you please show me where to find out your answer? (link to the document, because I want to get more things, example userid)

Comment: See this: http://justmeteor.com/blog/adding-attributes-to-the-user-object-when-creating-a-new-user/